# Why is DotNetCoreCLI test taking to much time?

Tags: azure, devops

I am trying to discover a way to fix too much time executing unit test. the azure command line is frorzen in this line: [image: command line].

and this is my yml code:

```
 - task: DotNetCoreCLI@2
  inputs:
    command: 'test'
    projects: '$(solutionUnitTest)'
    testRunTitle: 'Unit Tests'
```

Comment: How much time is too much time? How long do tests take when you run the locally? Are those times comparable? What do your tests do? ...

Comment: my tests late a couple of minutes but the azure DevOps late 60 minutes which is the time out.

Comment: If even with a simple dummy tests (an empty TestMethod basically) the issue still persists, it has nothing to do with your tests. Guiding the direction in which to look next.
Otherwise you could start narrowing down the issue by disabling (or commenting) all tests, then add them back one by one (or category/group-wise) and see what happens.

Comment: I have commented all test methods and the azure pipeline has passed. Now I should uncommenting tests one by one?

Comment: Yup, exactly. Find the culprit.